# Convert double to int without rounding java

Tags: java

i would like to know how to convert a double to int without rounding in java, for example 3,9 double to 39 int, thanks in advance !

Comment: This is multiplication, not conversion.

Comment: double will have decimal part and in will never have decimal part. what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: i have this number 3.98987 or other inputs like 6.8728, i want them to convert without the (.), example 3.98987 to----> 398987

Comment: `3.9` cannot be represented in a Java `double` as an exact value; it's `3.8999999999999998` or the like under the hood. Please rephrase your question. (And as for your rephrasing, print to a string and delete the decimal point (or comma, or whatever it is in your locale).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you could convert your `double` to a `String`, remove the `.` and than try to parse it to an `int`.

By doing something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double input = 2.12345;
    String stringInput = String.valueOf(input);
    String withoutDot = stringInput.replace(".", "");

    try {
        int number = Integer.parseInt(withoutDot);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        // Handle this exception gracefully
    }
}
```

Be aware that with this solution you will always have a `NumberFormatException` when your `double` value has to many decimal points.

If your `double` values always have the same amount of decimal points (2 for example) another solution would be to use multiplication:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double input = 2.12;
    Double rounded = 2.12 * 100;
    int number = rounded.intValue();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately  they don't have always the same amount of decimal points, anyway that code worked! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

In general it's impossible. 
Because double can have much more digits then int.

```
    double d = 3.111111111111111111111111111111;
    System.out.println(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```